Expo - React native with react-native-google-signin/google-signin
I have a little problem with the google sign in function in my react native application. When I build the apk with Eas d'Expo, it works fine. I can connect.
But when I build the aab bundle for google play console and create a test version, nothing happens, the modal simply closes.
I did create my OAuth on Google cloud console. That's why it works fine on the APK.
I don't use Firebase and I followed the react native google sign in documentation: https://react-native-google-signin.github.io/docs/install
Thanks for your help!

Do you have all fingerprints in place, see https://react-native-google-signin.github.io/docs/setting-up/get-config-file#android-sha-1-certificate-fingerprint-note?

Yes of course. My app has been signed too.
